# Should I put my 2e2 tests before or after my WebAppDeployment in my pipeline?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, e2e-testing

I hope someone can help me

I am developing an api in dotnet, i am using azure devops and pipelines in yaml.

I have already done my 2e2 test of the api where I basically make real calls to the api that I am developing, in order to test a real user flow within the application.

My question is the following should:

1- Do the 2e2test task before the deployment to my webapp allowing me to know that there is a problem before it is deployed to the resource, but having the problem that I would not be testing with the changes of the present commit (since I would be testing with the previous one because I still I have not deployed the resource)

or

2-do the task 2e2test after the deployment to my webapp, allowing me the tests to be carried out with the changes I made in the commit reflected in the resource and in this way know that what I did gave a problem or not, but having the problem that As the resource was deployed, if there was a problem, it would already be contaminating my webapp.

the yaml I'm working on is:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/ChatbotService/*.csproj'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    modifyOutputPath: true


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet MockUnitTest'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/MockUnitTest/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet E2ETest'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/E2ETest/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'bla blab bla'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'webapp-chatbotservice-dev'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ChatbotService/**/*.zip'
    AppSettings: '-ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deploy first and then run your e-2-e tests but not on production. On production you should run [smoke tests](https://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/smoke-testing/) which are kind of e-2-e tests which test crucial parts of your app without changing state of the app. (of course it makes sense to run them after deployment)

So it could be in high-level like this:

```
- build stage
- deploy to test env stage
  - run e-2-e test
- deploy to prod env stage
  - run smoke test
```

There is always a risk if you run test on not updated env as your test may verify part of app which are not deployed yet.